# Data Factory Blob Storage Linked Service with Managed Identity : The remote server returned an error: (403)

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have created a linked service connection to a storage account using a managed identity and it successfully validates but when I try to use the linked service on a dataset I get an error:

> A storage operation failed with the following error 'The remote server returned an error: (403)

The error is displayed when I attempt to browse the blob to set the file path.

The managed identity for the data factory has been assigned the Contributor role.

The blob container is set to private access.

Anyone know how I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong role. Just need to add an assignment for 
Storage Blob Data Contributor.